# How to get authentication scheme from httpclient?

Tags: httpclient

Im using apache httpclient for connecting to a url.Whenever Im getting a 401 error I want to know server's authentication scheme?
like Response code is getting like response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() similarly how to get which auth scheme?

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient tutorial is your friend.

---

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/"); 
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);

AuthState targetAuthState = (AuthState) localContext.getAttribute(ClientContext.TARGET_AUTH_STATE);
System.out.println("Target auth scope: " + targetAuthState.getAuthScope());
System.out.println("Target auth scheme: " + targetAuthState.getAuthScheme());
```

---